# Problems with website for mobile

Tags: iphone, mobile, browser, web, href

I'm practising on a mobile website but I'm encountering two problems.

On my iPhone I'm able to press the button down in the middle of the Safari Browser and use 'Add to homescreen' in order to place an 'app icon' on my iPhone screen between the other apps. When I press the icon of my site, it obviously redirects me to my website and (thanks to a javascript file) hides the browser navigation bars. Though, when I press an 'a href' link on the site, I'm being taken back to the safari browser to open it there.

I think this is because I wrote it like this:

And on my mobile, I'm accessing the site by an IP address.
Is there any way to solve this?

--

The other problem:

When I use 'add to homescreen' in Safari, I'm supposed to give it a name. It's automatically using my 'title' given in the HMTL file. But how am I supposed to give the app an icon? It's currently just using some sort of a screenshot of the website as the icon ..

Answer (score 1):

[iphone-app-icon-html-web-app-home-screen-icon](http://alvinalexander.com/iphone/iphone-app-icon-html-web-app-home-screen-icon)

The iPhone Mobile Safari web browser recognizes a special HTML tag that lets you add an iPhone app icon to your HTML application. Here's the syntax that lets you add an iPhone app icon to your web app:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/my-app-icon.png" />
```

This HTML link tag with the apple-touch-icon in the REL field tells the iPhone Mobile Safari browser to use this icon as the app icon for your web app.

iPad and iPhone app icon pixel size

To support the higher-resolution iPhone 4, your iPhone app icon should be a 114 by 114 pixel icon. Older iPhones used 56x56 pixel icons (or possibly 57x57), and the iPad uses a 72x72 pixel icon, and the image you supply will be scaled down and work on all of these devices. Here's a quick summary:

```
iPhone 4 - 114x114 pixels
Older iPhone - 57x57 pixels
iPad (version 1) - 72x72 pixels
```

If you prefer a little more control of your app icon size, Apple's documentation shows the following examples:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
```